# Is it possible to export documentation to PDF with hyperlink relinking?

Tags: export, documentation, pdf-format

I am establishing local Mathematica documentation website. We're decided export documentation to PDF, then display the pdf files in the browser.

But currently we found the hyperlink will become to normal text after exporting.
[image]

Is it possible to export to PDF with all links available ? And relinking these links ? (e.g **paclet:guide/Expression** becomes to **http://mySite.com/guide/Expression**)

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Mathematica? I just test this and exporting a notebook with a test hyperlink works in M11.0.1 (but unfortunately the hyperlink loses its coloring... not ideal)